# JQuery Setting preselected values for bootstrap select picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to pre-select multiple values from the below dropdown select. For this example i want to select 'Abbey' & 'Belgrave'

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple>
    <option value='Belgrave'>Belgrave</option>
    <option value='Abbey'>Abbey</option>
    <option value='Castle'>Castle</option>
</select>
```

I can achieve this manually which works fine like this:

```
$('#dropdown').selectpicker('val', ['Abbey', 'Belgrave']);
```

The problem is by passing the array in string it does not work:

```
var wards = dsFilterOptions.Wards.split(",");
var strWard = "[";
for (i = 0; i < wards.length; i++) {
    strWard += "'" + wards[i] + "',";
}
strWard = strWard.slice(0, -1); //remove last comma
strWard += "]";
$('#dropdown').selectpicker('val', strWard);
```

The above does not select the Abbey & Belgrave values.What i can do.

Comment: Since you're trying to set 2 values, I presume it is a multiselect. You should add `multiple` to the `<select>`

Comment: Ninsly I already have multiple in the select :- updated above

Comment: Oh ok. Is there any problem with just doing `$('#dropdown').selectpicker('val', wards);`

Comment: What is the initial string you're working with? And why, after splitting it into an array, are you converting it back into a string?

Comment: David the initial str is built from the user input and does not have the 'apostrophe' around the value hence i am going through the str and formatting it with ' ' . And directly using it does not work also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `JSON.parse` to revert the string to an array, so:

```
$('#dropdown').selectpicker('val', JSON.parse(strWard));
```

Edit, with single quotes fixed:

```
var wards = dsFilterOptions.Wards.split(",");
var strWard = '[';
for (i = 0; i < wards.length; i++) {
    strWard += '"' + wards[i] + '",';
}
strWard = strWard.slice(0, -1); //remove last comma
strWard += ']';
$('#dropdown').selectpicker('val', JSON.parse(strWard));
```

Comment: Tried this but did not work: error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @user2906420 This is due to single quotes in your string. I'll edit my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`response.user_accounts` is an array, but it just shows the first value as a dropdown selection, not all values of the array. Please suggest

```js
if (response.user_accounts) {
          $('#account').selectpicker('val', response.user_accounts.account_id);
        }
```